# Neo4j: JVM tuning properties ignored

Tags: neo4j

I installed Neo4j Community Edition 2.3.3 on a macbook air with 8GB of RAM. I'm trying to connect to a local database using the web interface.

My local db is quite large: ~200GB, ~600,000,000 nodes and ~1,000,000,000 of relationships.

Using the GUI I went to the options and I edited the file:

```
/Users/<user>/Documents/Neo4j/.neo4j-community.vmoptions
```

adding these two lines:

```
-server
-Xmx4096M
```

as explained here: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/performance-guide.html
but those parameters are ignored.
When I try to start the db I get:

```
Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@b14302e' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
```

And the messages.log file shows:

```
JVM memory information:
Free  memory: 74.67 MB
Total memory: 123.00 MB
Max   memory: 1.78 GB
```

P.S.:

The database was create on a linux (more powerful) machine where everything works fine. I copied the data/ directory locally.

**EDIT**

I tried with a fresh database, and the problem persists. It looks like neo4j 2.3.3 for mac is just broken. The server runs but the jvm parameters in

```
.neo4j-community.vmoptions
```

are ignored. I also tried to write random characters in that file and the JVM runs smoothly. I opened up an issue on github: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/6810

**UPDATE**

The issue has been tagged as an operability bug. No clear solution yet.

Comment: is there more to that error message in either of the log files?

Comment: Nothing really interesting (to me) in any of the log files. They all confirm that the jvm parameters have been ignored.